# How to display a layout with hybrid composition of Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I've read [how host native Android and iOS views on flutter](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-views). As you can see the exemple about **Hybrid composition** (Android Side) they return directly a TextView. How I must do to load a layout file.